# JavaFX: Binding Timeline's duration to a property

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have an application that has a combobox with some double values. The user can select any of the values. The application has a "[TimeLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html)" attached to it that will print a statement on the console. The [sscce](http://sscce.org/) is below. What should happen is that is should print the text of the option selected from the combobox. Pls advise.

```
package just.to.test;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class TimerSample extends Application  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Text Fonts");

        Group g = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(g, 150, 100);

        ObservableList<Double> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        data.add(5.0);
        data.add(10.0);
        data.add(15.0);
        data.add(20.0);

        ComboBox<Double> timeOptions = new ComboBox<Double>(data);
        timeOptions.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();

        g.getChildren().addAll(timeOptions);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        final double timerInterval = timeOptions.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

        KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(timerInterval),
            new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("This is called every "
                        + timerInterval + " seconds");
                }
            });

        Timeline timerThread = new Timeline(keyFrame);
        timerThread.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        timerThread.play();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't bind a Timeline's duration to a property because the duration of a Keyframe in a Timeline is not a property and you can only bind properties to properties.

What you need to do instead is to listen for changes in the value of the combo-box and trigger create new key frames with the new durations when the user selects a new duration.  You also cannot modify the key frames of a running timeline, so you have to stop the timeline before you set the new keyframes for the timeline, then start the timeline after the new keyframes have been set.

*Sample Code*

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.*;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class TimerSample extends Application  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Group g = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(g, 150, 100);

        ComboBox<Double> timerOptions = createTimerOptions(
                0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0
        );
        g.getChildren().addAll(timerOptions);

        createTimer(timerOptions);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private ComboBox<Double> createTimerOptions(double... options) {
        ObservableList<Double> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        for (Double option: options) {
            data.add(option);
        }

        return new ComboBox<Double>(data);
    }

    private void createTimer(ComboBox<Double> timeOptions) {
        final Timeline timer = new Timeline();
        timer.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

        timeOptions.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Double>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Double> observable, Double oldValue, Double newValue) {
                resetTimer(timer, newValue);
            }
        });

        timeOptions.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
    }

    private void resetTimer(Timeline timer, final double timerInterval) {
        KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(
            Duration.seconds(timerInterval),
            new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    System.out.println(
                            "This is called every "
                                    + timerInterval
                                    + " seconds"
                    );
                }
            }
        );

        timer.stop();
        timer.getKeyFrames().setAll(
                keyFrame
        );
        timer.play();
    }
}
```

> just wondering if performance wise it is much heavier due to adding a new keyframe with every change in the combobox value.

Don't worry too much about performance in this case - this is a highly efficient operation.

There is no other solution than creating new key frames because key frames are [immutable objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html).

You could construct key frames up front or place them in something like a [LRU cache](http://mcicpc.cs.atu.edu/archives/2012/mcpc2012/lru/lru.html) as you lazily construct them, but in general the additional complexity involved will almost certainly not be worth it.

Comment: Works great. Thanks. But just wondering if performance wise it is much heavier due to adding a new keyframe with every change in the combobox value.

Comment: Updated answer based on additional questions.

Comment: Wouldn't `rateProperty()` be cleaner?

Comment: Yes, most likely, MouseEvent.

Answer (score 4):

All animations have a `rateProperty()` which can be changed on a **running animation!**

This seems like a much cleaner solution:

```
private void createTimer(ComboBox<Double> timeOptions) {
    Timeline timer = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1),
            evt-> System.out.println(
                        "This is called every "
                                + timeOptions.getValue()
                                + " seconds"
                ));

    timer.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    timer.rateProperty()
         .bind(new SimpleDoubleProperty(1.0)
         .divide(timeOptions.valueProperty()));

    timeOptions.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
}
```